# Continuously needing to reconnect to Wifi

Tags: wireless

I've been having wifi issues- I'll have a semi-weak signal and not be able to load webpages, but if I click on my internet on the drop down menu it will go through the reconnection process, possibly gain a bar or two, and then I'll be able to load pages. This repeats itself indefinitely. I'm on a desktop (with a wireless card), so it's not the power saver, and it's not the ipv6 issue, I don't think, as I tried disabling ipv6. (I'm not sure how prominent of an issue that is). 
Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing my wifi to act so strangely? No one else in my house has connectivity issues, and it certainly appears to be my computer, as I can reconnect and get internet access.

Added, output of lsusb:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
```

Comment: if it is an internal wireless card and not a usb wireless device, run this command instead `lspci -v`

Comment: Oh, whoops, I'll run that. It's internal.

Comment: Added, but it's kind of messy...

Comment: What version of ubuntu do you have installed? and if you recently installed, have you performed all the most recent updates. I have this same card and used to have similar problems but on the newest kernels things run great.

Comment: Please run `uname -r` and `sudo iwconfig` thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running a newer version of ubuntu, run the following commands to update your kernel:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then, reboot for the changes to take effect.

Assuming you are already running the newest kernel, run the following command to increase the retry limit which can be a problem and will cause the problems you are experiencing if set too low (default is set to 7):

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 retry 12
```

If changing iwconfig settings works for you you'll have to do that each time you reboot.

If you are running ubuntu 12.04 please let me know and I'll include instructions on how to build the driver from source available from the realtek website (will only install on 12.04 and will not compile on a newer kernel).

Comment: Nope, I'm running 14.04. I think my kernel was fully updated- so I'll see if the second command does anything. The problem seems to have occurred once already after changing. I'll report back shortly...

Comment: @Anthony one more thing. In my router settings, I have an option for "noreply" and if I have that enabled I'll end up with the same issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Where is that located?

Comment: access the router, usually through a browser, http://192.168.1.1 or whatever your default route is listed

Comment: I'll fiddle with that if the issue happens again. As it is, I set retry a little higher, (I forget to what) and it *seems* okay. Right now it's hard to get into the router- I don't know the password! 

In any case, it does seem like the retry setting is working. I'll accept this answer! Thank you!

Comment: I think it *is* set, my housemate is paying and it's tied to his comcast account- but he tried logging in with his information and it didn't work. I'll probably need to call comcast to see how to fix it, but that seems like a lot of work...

Comment: Oh I found the default username/password, where is this setting you're talking about?

Comment: I think it's just out of my hands, the brower URL has the comcast logo- I don't think I can manage it.